# VS Code - Multi group Search Replace with Regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find a way to replace the search matched group with another group. 
Like below - 
Input :

```
aaa bbb aaa
ccc bb eee aaa
```

Expected Output :

```
xxx yyy xxx
ccc bb eee xxx
```

However I am not able to get this achieved in vscode.

I am able to do this in notepad++ is like below with regex option enabled -

```
Search for   : (aaa)|(bbb)
Replace with : (?{1}xxx)(?{2}yyy)
```

Comment: I guess VSCode doesn't support conditional replacement, you have to do the job in 2 step, 1) replace aaa with xxx 2) replace bbb with yyy

Comment: The reason I can't do the two step process is the replacing value can be dynamic.

Comment: hmm.. what do you mean by 'replacing value can be dynamic'? If it is dynamic, it might be better to modify via a script such as Python or bash?